# ADD both services Google API NearbyPlace service and own data service ,and to show data in Android

Tags: android, json

Google Api Provide Nearbyplace data When We pass lat and log,..I want to My services with Google api services...Have any Example or how To approach this..

Thanks,
Adisheshu.

Answer (score 0):

Google Api Provide Nearbyplace data
visit https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en